# dataframe to presence/absence dataframe with 2 columns as comma separated strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, the first one (annotations) is what I want to measure presence absence on and the latter two columns (categories, CUI_desc) contain comma separated strings of factors that I would like to become columns for a presence/absence dataframe

Currently, the data looks like this:

```
annotations                        categories                                   CUI_desc
heroine                            ['heroic', 'opioid', 'substance_abuse']      ['C0011892___heroin']
heroin                             ['heroic', 'opioid', 'substance_abuse']      ['C0011892___heroin']
he smoked two packs a day          ['opioid', 'substance_abuse']                ['C0439234___year', 'C0748223___QUIT', 'C0028040___nicotine']
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
annotations               heroic   opioid   substance_abuse   COO1892___heroin   CO439234___year   CO748223___QUIT   COO22840___nicotine
heroine                   1        1        1                 1                  0                 0                 0
heroin                    1        1        1                 1                  0                 0                 0
he smoked two packs a day 0        1        1                 0                  1                 1                 1
```

I used this line of code from a similar question:

```
from collections import Counter
test = pd.DataFrame({k:Counter(v) for k, v in master.items()}).T.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

But got an undesired output:

```
                  heroine         heroin         he smoked two packs a day
annotations       1               1              1
categories        0               0              0
CUI_desc          0               0              0
```

It seems to be counting how many times a certain annotations shows up in my dataframe. This is likely because the above block of code is for a dictionary and not a dataframe.

Comment: You may want to look at `explode` and `pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: OP clarified that each cell is a string so we need to convert it into a list first before calling `explode`.

Assuming the index is unique:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

categories = pd.get_dummies(master['categories'].apply(literal_eval).explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
cui_desc = pd.get_dummies(master['CUI_desc'].apply(literal_eval).explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
pd.concat([master['annotations'], categories, cui_desc], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
              annotations  heroic  opioid  substance_abuse  C0011892___heroin  C0028040___nicotine  C0439234___year  C0748223___QUIT
                  heroine       1       1                1                  1                    0                0                0
                   heroin       1       1                1                  1                    0                0                0
he smoked two packs a day       0       1                1                  0                    1                1                1
```

Comment: The annotations category may not be unique, which is a problem I hadn't forseen. Would this still work with redundancies?

Comment: Yes, it should. It requires that each row be uniquely indexeed (usually with an integer). So unless your `master` frame was indexed with `annotations`, it should be fine

Comment: Just ran it, I think the major issue is that it does not separate the features into separate columns. For instance, instead of making two separate columns for "aggression" and "irritability" it puts them together

Comment: I will need a bigger data set to see what you mean. Updated the answer with my test output

Comment: In other words "['aggression', 'irritability', 'confusion', 'injury', 'dosage', 'opioid', 'substance_abuse']" is a column when it should be 6 separate columns

Comment: Did you forget the `explode`?

Comment: No, I copied and pasted as you put it. Hmm, not sure why we are getting different results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238628/discussion-between-code-different-and-melderon).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `Series.value_counts`

```
import ast 

def row_value_counts(row):
    return row.apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts()

test = (
    df.set_index("annotations")
      .apply(row_value_counts, axis=1)
      .fillna(0)
      .astype(int)
      .reset_index()
)
```